# Error installing Marble: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of marble

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I've a Raspberry Pi 3 with Debian 8 Jessie and I'm trying to install Marble but I can't. I've this error and I don't know what to do now...

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ sudo dpkg -i marble_4.14.2-1_armhf.deb
(Reading database ... 131700 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack marble_4.14.2-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking marble (4:4.14.2-1) over (4:4.14.2-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of marble:
marble depends on marble-data (>= 4:4.14.2-1); however:
Package marble-data is not installed.
marble depends on marble-plugins (= 4:4.14.2-1); however:
Package marble-plugins is not installed.
marble depends on kde-runtime (>> 4:4.10); however:
Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.
marble depends on libkdecore5 (>= 4:4.11); however:
Package libkdecore5 is not installed.
marble depends on libkdeui5 (>= 4:4.11); however:
Package libkdeui5 is not installed.
marble depends on libkio5 (>= 4:4.11); however:
Package libkio5 is not installed.
marble depends on libknewstuff3-4 (>= 4:4.11); however:
Package libknewstuff3-4 is not installed.
marble depends on libkparts4 (>= 4:4.11); however:
Package libkparts4 is not installed.
marble depends on libmarblewidget19 (= 4:4.14.2-1); however:
Package libmarblewidget19 is not installed.
marble depends on libplasma3 (>= 4:4.11); however:
Package libplasma3 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package marble (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.3-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
marble
```

Comment: `dpkg` is a way to install a package that will *not* install any dependencies, and `marble` has quite a few. Try to do `sudo apt install -f` and see if that installs the dependencies for you (it will remember that you wanted them).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find any solution because you do not understand the problem.

The 'marble' package has a bunch of *dependencies*. These dependencies are required for marble to work.

Packaging dependencies separately keeps each package small, and ensures that you install only what you really need for the software to work. It allows each dependency to be patched or upgraded separately. It keeps the size of your installed system small. It prevents 'dll hell', with multiple versions of shared libraries on the same system.

In short, separately-packaged dependencies are one of the great benefits of using a Debian-based system.

Now go back and read each error message again. It should make a bit more sense now.

**There are two ways to solve your problem**

The simplest way is to use apt instead of dpkg. Apt will automatically download and install dependencies, and is the recommended package manager for most Debian-based systems.

For example, in Ubuntu 16.04 and Debian 8 (and newer) the following command will do everything for you:

```
sudo apt install marble
```

The older method is to use dpkg. dpkg won't download and install dependencies - it merely installs or uninstalls the package that it's instructed to. Apt is built on top of dpkg precisely to handle your use case: A lot of dependencies to download and install.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was my problem, I've trying to download each package individually.